# memorize/monitoring user behavior in app

Tags: xcode, uitableview, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

I'm new to swift, or new to coding to be more specific.

I am now developing a online ordering app with swift 3 and xcode 8.
and the problem I'm facing is that I have no idea how to track user's behavior in app .

For example (in case i use ambiguous terms)

1. Ian tapped a tableview cell (French Frires / $3) in viewController 1
2. then Ian tapped a tableview cell (Pepsi / $1.5) in viewController 2
3. VC3 shows what Ian just ordered and total Ian have to pay

(or maybe it doesn't even need three VCs to complete this task)

I am now using Google Authentication and Firebase BTW.

I did some research, but turns out not really helping.

I know it's kind of a big question but any tips is appreciated

or any tips for the the keywords I should google?

Thanks.

Comment: You usually don't get tips when food is ordered online. That's more for restaurants. And I can't quite see how Google Authentication and Firebase are in any way relevant to this. You just need to remember which items the customer wanted to order.

Comment: if there's a user ordering meals via my app, how do I get

Comment: like a CSV file or anything like that for what he order ? 
and thanks for replying !

Comment: I thought maybe what he ordered will be send to Firebase database or something :/

Comment: ah! I will give it a try. thanks for the tip :D

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a different node in your DB, named :- **ordersPlaced** and then in subNodes give the order key as the userID and value as the order placed or the order'S ID's

Suggested JSON Tree:-

```
yourAPP:{
  USERS : {
      user1 : {...},
      user2 : {...},
      user3 : {...},
      user4 : {...},
      user5 : {...},
      ....
      },
  food_Items : {
      food_Item1 : {...},
      food_Item2 : {...},
      food_Item3 : {...},
      food_Item4 : {...},
      food_Item5 : {...},
      ...
       },
  ordersPlaced : {
      user1 : {
          timeStamp : 121321421231,
          food_Item2 : true,
          food_Item5 : true,
             } 
      }  

}
```